# Maximizing a Window moves minimize,maximize and close button to the left

Tags: 11.04

I want when i maximized a window for the minimize,maximize and close buttons to not go left but stay right like in Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the question, I believe this relates to the Unity interface in Ubuntu 11.04.  If the window controls are switched to the right of the screen, they function correctly when an application is running in a window.  However, if the application is maximized, the window controls switch to the left side of the screen.

While this may be considered to be a bug, since the user has indicated a preference for the "normal" (i.e. historical) location of the window controls by changing the system configuration, it is apparently a designed-in feature, related to positioning the controls in the top panel.

See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/natty/panel where it is stated that "When you maximize an application, the window controls (Close, Minimize, Maximize) are moved into the panel to give you more vertical working space."

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trick.

```
Press alt+f2.
Type gconf-editor.
Select apps/metacity/general
Look for button_layout and change the value in to this.
menu:minimize,maximize,close
```

The button will change right then and then from left to right. if it wont change try logging out.

$ sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart

note: before colon (:) means the buttons are on left side and after colon (:) means the buttons are on the right side.

or if your still confuse visit this link http://www.cebuntu.com/how-to/changing-window-button-from-left-to-right/

Comment: Please note that this works in Lucid, but hopefully works with Natty.

Comment: The above method will not work on natty. It only works until 10.10.

Comment: thanks for ur answer ,i know this but i mean the buttons that go to left when u maximize in minimize its ok and its in right .