# How to keep buttons layout when maximize windows on Natty?

Tags: window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I move the Window buttons from left to right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579/how-do-i-move-the-window-buttons-from-left-to-right)

How to keep buttons layout when maximize windows on Natty?

With my Ubuntu Natty, I have a problem as following: 
in the normal window, the button layout of windows is in Mac style but when I maximize windows, the buttons layout has change into Elementary style. I want to keep the same Mac Style when maximize window. I've searched much on web but I cannot find the solution.
Anyone has solved this problem, please help me.
thx so much!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Maximizing a Window moves minimize,maximize and close button to the left](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40733/maximizing-a-window-moves-minimize-maximize-and-close-button-to-the-left), you can't.

Comment: Thx Egil, but I mean that: in the normal window: 3 buttons Close, minimize, maximize in Mac style (red, yellow, green color). When i maximize the window, I want this buttons' layout keep on the same Mac style on Panel (not in Elementary style or another).

Comment: At last I find the solution for this. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/unity-panel-button-replacements-for-elementary-and-orta/